# how to prevent workTicker and breakTicker function to go into negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a pomodoro clock. The application is almost done; however, when adding and subtracting numbers the number can go into negative. And that's not desire. The workTicker and breakTicker function are responsible for this. I implemented an if statement that check whether the number is > than 1. But when the number is = 1, it will no longer execute. How can I implement this? thanks codepen: https://codepen.io/zentech/pen/vJGdjN
javascript / jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //variables
  var session;
  var seconds;
  var minutes; 
  var clockDisplay = document.getElementById("display"); 
  var counterId = 0;
  var state = "work";
  var start; //getting start time 

  //start / stop clock listener functionality
  $("#start").click(function() {
    var value = $(".button").text();
    console.log(value);
    if(value == "Start") {
      session = Number($(".work").text() * 60);
      start = new Date().getTime();
      state = "work";
      console.log("started!");
      //starting counter
      counterId = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
      $("#session").text("Work");
      $(".button").text("Stop");
    } else {
      console.log("stopped");
      // | 0 same as Number()
      session = (($(".work").text() * 60) | 0);
      //clear counter
      clearInterval(counterId);
      clockDisplay.innerHTML = (session/60) +":00";  
      $("#session").text("Session");
      $(".button").text("Start");
    }  
  });

  //add work time
  $('.plusWork').click(function() {
    var value = "plus";
    console.log(value);
    workTicker(value);
  });

  //substract work time
  $('.minWork').click(function() {
    var value = "minus";
    workTicker(value);
  });

  //add break time
  $('.plusBreak').click(function() {
    var value = "plus";
    breakTicker(value);
  });

  //substract break time
  $('.minBreak').click(function() {
    var value = "minus";
    breakTicker(value);
  });

 //work countdown timer function
  function countDown() {
    //getting time now in ms
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    /*difference since clock started. now and start are in ms
    we need to / by 1000 to bring to sec*/
    var diff = Math.floor(session - ((now - start) / 1000));
    console.log("diff: "+diff+" min: "+Math.floor(diff/60)+" sec: "+Math.floor(diff%60));
    //getting minutes
    minutes = Math.floor((diff / 60));
    //getting seconds
    seconds = Math.floor((diff % 60));
    //dealing with minutes and sec under 10: 09, 07...
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0"+minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0"+seconds : seconds;
    //update clock display
    clockDisplay.innerHTML = minutes+":"+seconds;

    //if difference reached < 0 stop counter;
    if(diff == 0) {    
      restartSession(state);
    }  
  }

  //add substract work from timer/display
  function workTicker(value) {
    var min = Number($('.work').text());
    //add substract while min > 0
    if(min > 1) {
      (value == "plus") ? min++ : min--;
      clockDisplay.innerHTML = min+":00";
      $(".work").text(min);
      console.log(min);
    }  
  }

  //add substract break time 
  function breakTicker(value) {
    var min = Number($(".break").text());
    //add substract as long as min > 0
    if(min > 1) {
      (value == "plus") ? min++ : min--;
      $(".break").text(min);
    }    
  }

  //restart countdown clock 
  function restartSession(state) {
    //if state is work, change to break and visebersa
    if(state == "work") {
      alert("Stop working!");
      $("#session").text("Break")
      session = $(".break").text();
    } else {
      alert("Get to work!");
      $("#session").text("Work");
      session = $(".work").text();
    }
    clearInterval(counterId); //clear counter
    console.log("session: "+session+" state: "+state);
    start = new Date().getTime(); //setting start time
    session = Number(session * 60); //converting min to sec
    state = state == "work" ? "break" : "work";
    counterId = setInterval(countDown, 1000); //starting counter
  }
});
```

Comment: Your conditionals seems to not match the comment directly above them.  1 > 0 == true.  Though, if the value is plus, do you really care?  You really only care if it is minus.  `if (value == "plus" || min > 0)`

Comment: not sure what you mean, but shouldn't your conditionals be `min > 0` instead of `min > 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking only if user is trying to subtract...

```
  function breakTicker(value) {
    var min = Number($(".break").text());
    //add substract as long as min > 0
    if(value == "plus") {
      min++ 
    } else {
      if(min > 1){
         min--;
      }
    }
      $(".break").text(min);  
  }
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzmLLd

Comment: Is that what you were asking about, @miatech?

Comment: Thanks... one question. Can you duplicate my code? isn't that plagiarism?

Comment: What? I was just trying to help you and give you an example, I really have no intent to steal your code. Believe or not, I have better things to do than stealing your pomodoro timer code.

Comment: And accusing of plagiarism is not a best way to say thanks for fixing your damn code. (Hint: marking as accepted is).